Can't delete the session of another user in nodejs
I am using session based authentication for the first time. I have been reading and wathcing tutorials. I would like to know how to end the session of another user.
I know that I can use this line of code:
req.session.destroy();

to end the session of a user but this works if the user is the person carrying out the action on it own session. The session would be available in req object.
How ever I would like to have an admin who can end the session of any other user. According to what I found on express website, store.destroy(sid, callback) is explained this way:

This required method is used to destroy/delete a session from the store given a session ID (sid). The callback should be called as callback(error) once the session is destroyed.

I felt this is exactly what I am looking for since it has an argument for sessionId. But it didn't work for me. I used it this way req.session.destroy('sessionId', );
I tried adding callback and it alerted me that it only expected one argument which is a callback.
So, how do I achieve my goal? I would like a user like an admin who can destroy the session of other users using their sessionId.
By the way, I am using redisStore via connect-redis package and my session is setup this way:
export const createSession = session({
store: new RedisStore({client: redisClient, }),
secret: sanitizedConfig.SESSION_SECRET,
resave: false,
saveUninitialized: false,
name: sanitizedConfig.SESSION_NAME,
cookie:{
maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60,
secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true: false,
httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? true : false

}
});

I have updated my question. I am using redisStore.

req.sessionStore.destroy(sessionID, callback)?

would redisStore be the npm package called connect-redis?

Yes, exactly. That is what I am using

Well, did my suggestion help?

Where is the suggestion, please?

my (now) FIRST comment? or, to be able to delete outside of a request, you would create const store = new RedisStore({ client: redisClient}); ... you would use store: store i your session setup, and then you can simply store.destroy(sessionID, callback)

Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.
